# How to add variables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a variable that I need to show it by month. This variable is a boolean and if its set True, it means that the app was installed.

Example:
variable = intalled apps

In January there were 20 installed apps.
In February there were 10 installed apps.
In March there were 5 installed apps.

I want to show on the table all the apps that were installed (boolean = True):

```
January: 20

February: 20 (January) + 10 =  30

March: 20 (January) + 10 (February) + 5 (March) = 35
```

Does anyone know how I could do this in Mysql?

Thanks

Comment: Show your efforts and please post some sql you tried.

Comment: please provide something to go on.  like table structures and any sql you have attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I GOT IT! I used the recursive

`SELECT (select id_time from database.dim_time where id_time = a.fk_time) AS yearmonth, (select sum( if( installed in (1), 1,0)) as installed from database.facts_table where fk_time <= yearmonth ) as installed FROM database.facts_table AS a GROUP BY yearmonth ORDER BY yearmonth ASC`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery to group installations by month.  Then you can us a variable in the outer query to calculate the cumulative sum:

```
select  installation_year
,       installation_month
,       installation_count
,       (@running_sum:= @running_sum + installation_count) as cumulative_sum
from    (
        select  year(installation_date) as installation_year
        ,       month(installation_date) as installation_month
        ,       count(*) as installation_count
        from    YourTable
        group by
                installation_year
        ,       installation_month
        ) as SubQueryAlias
join    (select @running_sum := 0) as InitVars
order by 
        installation_year
,       installation_month
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/321a3/6/0)

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
Select COUNT(*),Month 
From Apps
where installed = true
group by Month
```

Comment: How would this add the number of installation in january to the number of installations in february?

Comment: Just do this and then sum up the specific ranges you want on the fly in whatever language you're using to query the db.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it's just a simple query with an order by.

```
select COLUMNS_YOU_WANT from TABLE_NAME 
where YOUR_BOOLEAN == True 
order by SOME_DATE_COLUMN
```

Hopefully you're proficient enough in SQL to replace the sections with what you need.

Comment: It's not about ordering the rows. I want a sum of aps installed. Just like an evolution of installation.

Comment: Okay, that wasn't clear at all in the first post. Just, get a sum of each month and then do the addition afterwards on the PHP/Python side. Are you querying the DB manually or programatically? Don't make SQL do more than it needs to. A rolling sum in PHP/Python is easy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have an "Applications" table that contains an "Installed" column and an "InstalledDate" column.  If so...

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM   Applications
WHERE  Installed = 1 -- Assumes a bit/boolean column.
AND    InstalledDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate;
```

Scott

Comment: I got it! I used the recursive:

Comment: SELECT 
    
(select id_time from database.dim_time where id_time = a.fk_time) AS yearmonth,

(select sum( if( installed in (1), 1,0)) as installed
        from database.facts_table
        where fk_time <= yearmonth
) as installed,

FROM database.facts_table AS a
GROUP BY yearmonth
ORDER BY yearmonth ASC;